# Redirecting based on query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi all I need to redirect based on query string though htaccess in Apache.

I want that all the queries that contain jjj redirect to my homepage

I used the code below but its not working could you please help me¿

Thanks in advance,

Mauri

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^jjj$
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.eventosbarcelona.com  [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rule redirects **example.com/?jjj** to **example.com/?jjj** I guess, You are getting redirect loop error as both urls are same. By default, mod-rewrite appends old query strings to the destination url. You need to use a **?** at the end of the Rewrite destination url to discard query string.

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^jjj$
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com? [L,R]
```

This will redirect **/?jjj** to **http://example.com/** .

Comment: Hi, I´ve tried this                                                                                    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^jjj$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.eventosbarcelona.com? [L,R]                                                      But still not working, it redirect to the same page